# using a yii widget from a view

Tags: php, yii

This seems like it should be dead simple, but I'm struggling.

So, the following line works great when I have it in a layout. That is, from "/protected/views/layouts/baselayout.php" the line:

> $this->widget('BuildingList');

Works exactly like it should. It creates a building list.

However, when the same line of code is used in a *view*, it fails. That is, from "/protected/views/rooms/update.php" I get

> Include(/Var/Www/Html/Yii/Framework/Zii/Widgets/CWidget.Php): Failed To
>   Open Stream: No Such File Or Directory

For what it's worth, CWidget.php definitely isn't in "/zii/widgets". It's in "/framework/web/widgets"

But somehow Yii knows where to find the CWidget.php from the layout and not the view

Answer (score 0):

Try using the widget by its full name.

If it is in /protected/components, them:

```
$this->widget('application.components.BuildingList');
```

You can also add it to the 'import' section in your config file, like this:

```
'import'=> [ 
             'application.models.*', 
             'application.components.*', 
             'ext.*' 
           ],
```